# Unable to resolve module 'react-navigation-stack' Can't find a solution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Not sure what is happening but my react navigation isn't working on react native.

I have installed npm react-navigation-stack and npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens.

It is giving me this **error**:

```
Unable to resolve module 'react-navigation-stack' from 'routes/homeStack.js': react-navigation-stack could not be found within the project or these directories: ../node_modules
```

### I have this on my route folder:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import Home from "../screens/home";
import Decision from "../screens/decision";

const screens = {
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
  },
  Decision: {
    screen: Decision,
  },
};

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(screens);

export default createAppContainer(HomeStack);
```

### Then on my main App component, I have:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from "react-native";
import * as Font from "expo-font";
import Home from "./screens/home";
import { AppLoading } from "expo";
import Navigator from "./routes/homeStack";

const getFonts = () =>
  Font.loadAsync({
        "poppins-regular": require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf"),
        "poppins-bold": require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf"),
  });

export default function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded, setFontsLoaded] = useState(false);

  if (fontsLoaded) {
    return < Navigator />;
  } else {
    return (
      <AppLoading startAsync={getFonts} onFinish={() => setFontsLoaded(true)} />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your react-navigation version?
-> use @react-navigation/stack for v5

Comment: Yup this worked. Thank you! 
For some reason, I was using the old version